# Badge "unsung hero", accepted but not upvoted answer

Tags: discussion, badges

I noticed a badge "unsung hero", awarded if we have more than 10 accepted answers with zero votes, and which consist at least 25 per cent of the total of the answers. This badge have never been awarded.

So I have two questions:

- What is the goal of this badge?
- Why accept an answer without upvoting it?

Comment: On StackOverflow, questions on "long tail" topics tend not to get many views or votes at all, so it's much more plausible to get the *Tenacious* and *Unsung Hero* badges.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In regard to your second question, I do know from my unregistered days that unregistered users have the ability to accept answers, but don't have the ability to vote on anything. So this may be the reason behind at least some accepted answers with $0$ votes.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks.

Answer (score 10):

> What is the goal of this badge?

For fun. Like all other of the badges. (What? You are meant to take them seriously?)

Answer (score 8):

1. Exactly what it sounds like: recognizing people who write accepted answers that don't get upvoted.
2. Who knows? I've had this happen a couple of times myself. Some people probably don't realize that you can upvote things.

Comment: And do you know some users who almost get this bagde? Otherwise, maybe the 25 per cent is too much. I guess the reason you mention for the second question is the most probable. Thanks!

Comment: Davide, you have to understand that most of the badges were designed a long time ago and that (as far as I know) we do not have control over how they are awarded... this kind of stuff is really not worth worrying about.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't realized that.

Comment: @Davide: One good measure is to check StackOverflow/SuperUser to see if there are people holding this badge.

Comment: I checked, out of curiosity: this badge has been awarded [2672 times on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/226/unsung-hero).